# uninstalled bitnami from my pc still displayed in firefox

Tags: wamp

I have uninstalled bitnami and install wampserver ,and reboot pc already.
when i input `127.0.0.1` in my firefox,there is still a bitnami web displayed ,how can i  uninstall bitnami clearly?

[image]

Comment: How did you uninstalled bitnami?.Use bitnami uninstaller form bitnami installation folder or you have to manually remove files and services.

Answer (score 0):

A long shot, but have you tried clearing your browser history and cache?

Can you see the bitnami processes running in the task manager?

Another method would be to disable the Bitanmi services from msconfig and services.msc.